# Get five unique random PHP values selected from an array and put them in separate variables

Tags: php, arrays, string, random

I have an array, for example:

```
 array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");
```

I want to select five random and unique values from it and put them in five different variables, for example:

```
    $one = "ccc"; 
    $two = "aaa";
    $three = "bbb"; 
    $four = "ggg";
    $five = "ddd";
```

I have already found this code below which works for generating the random strings and just displaying them, but the output I want is for getting them in different variables and being able to use them separately.

```
<?php

$arr = $arr_history = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");

for ( $i = 1; $i < 5; $i++ )
{
  // If the history array is empty, re-populate it.
  if ( empty($arr_history) )
    $arr_history = $arr;

  // Randomize the array.
  array_rand($arr_history);

  // Select the last value from the array.
  $selected = array_pop($arr_history);

  // Echo the selected value.
  echo $selected . PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Comment: Do they have to be separate variables or can it be an array containing those five random values with numeric indexes?

Comment: BTW, your loop won't show five items because of your loop logic `$i = 1; $i < 5; $i++` you need to make it `<=`.

Comment: @Script47 I think it can work with the indexes too. I just need to be able to use them in different parts of the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `shuffle` the array and use `list` to assign the values

```
$arr = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");

shuffle( $arr );
list($one, $two, $three, $four, $five) = $arr;
```

Doc: [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: Thanks Script47. Happy to help @ClaudioDelgado :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$arr = $arr_history = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");
$random = [];

for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
{
  // If the history array is empty, re-populate it.
  if ( empty($arr_history) )
    $arr_history = $arr;

  // Randomize the array.
  array_rand($arr_history);

  // Select the last value from the array.
  $selected = array_pop($arr_history);

  array_push($random, $selected);
}

var_dump($random);
```

- I've fixed your loop logic so it now displays 5 items instead of 4.
- I am using the [short syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) for defining an array which requires 5.4 or above.

**Output**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ggg"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "fff"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "eee"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ddd"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "ccc"
}
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/TriangularPriceyOrganization)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    $arr = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");

    $tmp = $arr;
    array_rand($tmp);

    $one = $tmp[0];
    $two = $tmp[1];
    ...
```

Remeber though that it will not chech if the value in $tmp[n] actually exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shuffle` function of PHP to randomizes the order of the elements in the array, then take the first elements.

```
$randomArray = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg");
shuffle($randomArray);

$randomArray = array_slice($randomArray, 0, 5);

$randomArray[0]; //1st element
$randomArray[1]; //2nd element
$randomArray[2]; //3rd element...
```